# Is there any way to convert the test code to a MethodDeclaration using Eclipse JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

Assume that I already had a CompilationUnit unit parsed from a Java file. Now, I want to add some new complex methods to Java file. With the simple method such as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello" + " world");
}
```

we can manually program as example: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm

However, with complex method, it seems to be impossible. I think another solution is that: store the entire method to a String, then parse it and add the result to existing compilation unit.

Is there any way to convert the test code to a MethodDeclaration, then append to the existing compilation unit using eclipse JDT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here, that you are speaking of a [CompilationUnit](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/CompilationUnit.html) and a [MethodDeclaration](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/package-summary.html) in the [org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/package-summary.html) package.

> However, with complex method, it seems to be impossible.

Actually you could *theoretically* create any possible legal Java code using the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom` API, by creating and linking the corresponding [ASTNodes](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/package-summary.html) using the various [AST#new-methods](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/AST.html).

For complex code, it is however more convenient to parse existing statements using an [ASTParser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html). To do that, you must first set the source of the parser to the code of the statements, and then set the parser kind to `ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS`. Then, when creating an ASTNode by calling `ASTParser#createAST`, the returned node will be of type [Block](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Block.html). Before you can set this block as e.g. the block of a `MethodDeclaration`, you must copy the block to the existing `AST` by calling `ASTNode.copySubtree(ast, block)`.

Here is a complete example, that shows how this could be done:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration;

public class JdtDomExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // (1) somehow get an org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit, a TypeDeclaration, and a MethodDeclaration
        AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS8);
        CompilationUnit cu =  ast.newCompilationUnit();
        TypeDeclaration typeDecl = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
        typeDecl.setName(ast.newSimpleName("MyClass"));
        cu.types().add(typeDecl);
        MethodDeclaration method = cu.getAST().newMethodDeclaration();
        method.setName(ast.newSimpleName("myMethod"));
        typeDecl.bodyDeclarations().add(method);

        // (2) create an ASTParser and parse the method body as ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        parser.setSource("System.out.println(\"Hello\" + \" world\");".toCharArray());
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_STATEMENTS);
        Block block = (Block) parser.createAST(null);

        // (3) copy the statements to the existing AST
        block = (Block) ASTNode.copySubtree(ast, block);
        method.setBody(block);

        // show the result
        System.out.println(cu);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class MyClass {
  void myMethod(){
    System.out.println("Hello" + " world");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer and source code. It matches what I want.